# Server sent events - cross domain safari

Tags: php, safari, cross-domain, server-sent-events

I am developing an application that checks if my database has been updated, and if so, my app displays the new values.

Client side:

```
if(typeof(EventSource)!=="undefined") {
  var eSource = new EventSource("http://mydomain.org/app.php");
  eSource.onmessage = function(event) {}
}
```

Server side:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/event-stream");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
echo "data:Hello World\n\n";
?>
```

Now, everything works in Firefox and Chrome. The app wil run in a Safari-based browser. In Safari, I get

```
SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18: An attempt was made to break through the security policy of the user agent.
```

So this problem has something to do with cross-origin posting, even though Access-Control-Allow-Origin has a wildcard. Any way to make this work in Safari?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebKit doesn't support CORS in SSE yet. Solutions:

1. Fetch from the same origin, `new EventSource("/app.php");`
2. Use CORS-aware polyfill for Safari. https://github.com/Yaffle/EventSource
3. Create iframe at same origin that your SSE stream (`http://mydomain.org/iframe.html`), read same-origin stream in the iframe, and use `postMessage()` to send events to other origins.

Comment: Solution 1: HTML-file has to run from the hard drive (like a widget in a browser).
Solution 3: The user can give parameters for styling, so with an iFrame, it isn't possible to style the elements from another origin. 

It seems i will have to look in to solution 2.

Comment: @TomBroucke The iframe could be invisible.

Comment: Yes, I haven't used the postMessage() before, but this seems like a very good solution to my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What version of Safari?
I believe EventSource's CORS was broken until Chrome 25+ and Safari 6.1+.